# right alignment text radio button android programaticly

Tags: android, constructor, right-to-left, text-alignment, android-radiobutton

Hi I need to Create a custom  radio button class with two different picture for each state and RTL text. I made the button but i couldn't make text RTL for api 8 and upper . i would be happy if some one could help me

`RadioGroup crdg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup11);`

make Radio button

```
rdbt1 = new RadioButton(new ContextThemeWrapper(
            getApplicationContext(), R.style.styleName));

    rdbt1.setButtonDrawable(android.R.color.transparent);

rdbt1.setText("for example(RTL text)");
```

add RadioButton to Radio Group

```
crdg.addView(rdbt1);
```

styleName is

`<style name="styleName" parent="android:Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
        <item name="android:button">@null</item>
        <item name="android:drawableRight">@drawable/rdb_question_selector</item>
     </style>`

Comment: Can you post xml too please?

Comment: i don't use Xml because i want create radio button in java code

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the gravity to `Gravity.END`
So for example:

```
 RadioButton tempRadioButton = new RadioButton(this);
 tempRadioButton.setGravity(Gravity.END);
 tempRadioButton.setText("for example(RTL text)");
```

This will tell Android to align the text to the "end" of the view respecting RTL languages.

Answer (score 0):

add this

> forceRTLIfSupported();

in your oncreate()

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    private void forceRTLIfSupported()
    {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
            getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        }
    }
```